# Where webpack hosts the bundled files. windows

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

After running the application webpack creates a bundle.js and adds the reference on it into html. But where is the physical location of that bundled file?

Config

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");

const config = {
  entry: [
    './index.js',
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        use:[ 'css-loader' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loaders: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]some-module[\/\\]index\.js$/,
        loader: "imports-loader?define=>false"
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.css', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: { jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery' }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

thanks for helping...

Comment: When you say: "when i run webpack", you meant webpack-dev-server?

Comment: @MatheusSilva Yes, I'm using webpack-dev-server.

Answer (score 2):

> But where is the physical location of that bundled file?

When using with `webpack-dev-server`, webpack stores the bundles into a In-memory filesystem. Everything  happens in memory.